# Recursively search for RAR files and extract them, once extracted, remove them

Tags: command-line

I would like to recursively search a folder, extract the RAR file, and remove .nfo, .svf and the RAR files (*.rar and *.r1, *.r2, etc).

I found a command to recursively extract, but not to remove:

```
find ./ -name '*.rar' -exec unrar e {} \;
```

Answer (score 8):

Tack another `-exec` predicate (with `rm` inside that), which would only be run if the first one succeeds:

```
find . -name '*.rar' -exec unrar e {} \; -exec rm {} \;
```

`-exec rm {} \;` will only be run to remove the `.rar` file if the `unrar`-ing succeeds (`-exec unrar e {} \;`) i.e. `unrar` returns with exit status 0.

---

You can also do this using `bash`, using `globstar` option to recursively match glob pattern (`*.rar`), and `rm` each file if `unrar`-ing is successful:

```bsh
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.rar; do
    unrar e "$f" && rm "$f"
done
```

Comment: Alright thanks! I ran `find . -name '*.rar' -exec unrar e {} \; -exec rm {} \;` on a test folder, containing a divided rar archive. *.r01, *.r02, *.r03 etc, and ofc the *.rar file. The *.rar file was deleted, but not the rest of the archive. The rar segment files was still there (.r01,r02,r03,r04..)

Comment: @Adam You are matching only the `.rar` files with `-name '*.rar'`, try: `find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*\.r([[:digit:]]+|ar)$' -exec unrar e {} \; -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Thanks once again! But now I seems to try to unrar all segments. Maybe find the rar, and delete the rar and `.*\.r([[:digit:]]+|ar)$`?

Comment: @Adam I see, just append the removal of the segments upon success: `find . -name '*.rar' -exec unrar e {} \; -exec rm {} \; && rm *.r+([[:digit:]])` (assuming `extglob` option of `bash` is set, which is the default, otherwise set with `shopt -s extglob` first)

Answer (score 0):

```
cd FOLDER_WITH_RAR
find . -type f -name '*.rar' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
      dir=$(dirname "$file")
      rar=$(basename "$file")
      cd "$dir"
      echo "file=$file, dir=$dir, rar=$rar"
      unrar x "$rar"
      rm -f "$rar"
      cd -
    done
```